# Azure function ansible role erases default settings

Tags: deployment, ansible, azure-functions

I am using `ansible-role-azure-function` role to deploy Azure function.

If I use `azure_function_appsettings` parameter, it erases the rest of default app settings for entire Azure function application.

The settings below are nessesary for Auzre functions to work, but all they are gone after deploy:

```
 - AzureWebJobsDashboard 
 - AzureWebJobsStorage
 - FUNCTION_APP_EDIT_MODE
 - FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION
 - WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION
```

So if I add code to my deploy yml file:

```
azure_function_appsettings:
  - name: "SomeSetting1"
    value: "some value"
```

all settings above are gone except `APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY`.

So I have to manually add my `SomeSetting1` every time after deploying azure function.

Is there any way to preserve default app settings along with add my own?

Answer (score 0):

When you deploy your function using [`azure_rm_functionapp`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/azure_rm_deployment_module.html) with the ansible role, the default `deployment_mode` is `incremental`.

In incremental mode, Resource Manager leaves unchanged resources that exist in the resource group but aren't specified in the template.When redeploying an existing resource in incremental mode, all properties are reapplied. **The properties aren't incrementally added.**

[image]

Comment: So in this case, if the incremental mode is used by default why azure func app settings are erased?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the parameter name which should be used to add user custom settings is not **azure_function_appsettings** but **azure_function_customappsettings**